# How to setup a domain in apache

Tags: apache-2.2, domain

So Apache is installed and everything is working well.

Computers in the network can access my server by 192.168.1.1/website and it's good.

I was wondering how I could setup a name like testapache.wsd and use that as the site name. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a DNS server create an A record pointing your domain name at the ip address.  If you don't have a DNS server, you can do this using Host files, but you will need to set this up on all your client machines, which is a drag.